# How to use Callback function to get Orientation in Tizen?

Tags: c, linux, tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to write a native application in c to get the value of orientation in Tizen.
The compiled c code must be run on the Tizen phone and I need to get the Value of orientation. The callback function i got from Tizen source is

```
int app_cb_broker_appcore_rotation_event(enum appcore_rm rm, void *data)
{
    app_device_orientation_cb device_orientation_cb;

    device_orientation_cb = app_context.callbacks->device_orientation;

    if (device_orientation_cb != NULL)
    {
            app_device_orientation_e dev_orientation;

            dev_orientation = app_convert_appcore_rm(rm);

            device_orientation_cb(dev_orientation, app_context.user_data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to use this function to get the value of current orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the header file: 
https://review.tizen.org/git/?p=framework/appfw/app-core.git;a=blob;f=include/appcore-common.h;hb=HEAD

It looks like you should call `appcore_set_rotation_cb` to register a callback function to be informed when the rotation changes. If you want to get the existing state you can call `appcore_get_rotation_state`.

There's some sample code in the API docs included in the header file.